# Excel VBA cell comboBox (data validation list) set selected index?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am using Excel VBA to make an simple app, I have a **CELL** with **Data Validation** make it a **"ComboBox"**, can I use VBA code to set the **selectedIndex** for it? and how?

[image]

Comment: `CELL.Value = "Blah Blah"`

Comment: Thank, it's work, but how to run it when the sheet is load, the WorksheetActive event seem not work, and the WorkbookOpen event say the range is null (error), may be it's not constructed yet at Workbook open

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Blah Blah"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you need to "put some value into CELL when worksheet with CELL on it is opened" then try to insert following code into ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "%%SheetWithCELL%%" Then
        Sh.Range("CELL").Value = "%%NeededValue%%"
    End If
End Sub
```

Where

- %%SheetWithCELL%% - Name of sheet where CELL is located;
- %%NeededValue%% - Value, which you need to insert into CELL.

P.S. Code assumes that "CELL" is the actual name of some cell (named range)

Comment: Without check sheet name, we can still assign value by sheet name or index

Comment: Yes, but in this case Cell.Value will be set when **any** of sheets is selected.